# Changing from UIView to UIView in another class

Tags: objective-c, uiview

Here is a small problem I am having. I am not too good at programmatically changing views, but this is what I have:

```
//(.h)


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Detail.h"

@interface List : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) Detail *detail;
@end
```

and

```
//(.m)
@synthesize detail=_detail;

- (Detail *)detail
{
    NSLog(@"Detail UIView construction started.");
    if (_detail != nil)
    {
        return _detail;
    }

    Detail *aDetailView = [[Detail alloc] init];
    _detail = aDetailView;


    [self.view addSubview:_detail.view];
    //I never really set it to setHidden:YES, but just to make sure I'm setting it NO here.
    [_detail.view setHidden:NO];
    return _detail;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:self.detail.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight completion:nil];
}
```

As output:

```
2012-02-07 11:17:51.909 TodoApp[4232:fb03] Detail UIView construction started.
```

The view seems to do the FlipFromRight animation fine, but the screen is totally black.
As I said, I'm not good at changing views programmatically.

Thanks for any help!

=============
Answering my own question.

It was really stupid. The "Back" button in the Title bar had an unsupported configuration. So the View did not want to load... fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It was really stupid. The "Back" button in the Title bar had an unsupported configuration. So the View did not want to load... fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (Detail *)detail
{
NSLog(@"Detail UIView construction started.");
if (_detail != nil)
{
    return _detail;
}

Detail *aDetailView = [[Detail alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:aDetailView.view];
//I never really set it to setHidden:YES, but just to make sure I'm setting it NO here.
[aDetailView.view setHidden:NO];
_detail = aDetailView;

return _detail;
}
```

make these changes and let me know the result..

Comment: Nope, still black :( Nice try though. Changing views programmatically is hard. (I don't have a choice really, I must do it this way)

Answer (score 0):

you are returning  _detail before adding it to superview

so add this line

return _detail;

after this line  [self.view addSubview:_detail.view];

like this

```
[self.view addSubview:_detail.view];

[_detail.view setHidden:NO];

return _detail;
```

Comment: Will do quickly... EDIT: Nope still black.

Comment: You cant give a class a Frame, only a view. I will have to redo some code and make the Detail *aDetailView -> to -> UIView *aDetailView

Comment: If I change every Detail to UIView and then switch to the UIView it still changes to a black screen.

Comment: might be your view in IB is below uitableView in view hierarchy check it

Comment: the tableView is on the MasterViewController (Linked to MasterViewController.h) , the view I want to see is in Detail (linked to Detail.h) the tableView unfortunately has nothing to do with the View I want to see, only that when I click a cell, it must go to Detail.h's view.